# ; expected when using a Mouse Listener

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jlabel, mouselistener

I am trying to make a border appear when a user hovers their mouse over something, but when I use the paint Method. It says

```
Syntax Error on Token "(" ; expected and 
Syntax Error on Token ")" ; expected
```

My code is:

```
JLabel lblAllOrNothing = new JLabel("All Or Nothing (4 BP)");
lblAllOrNothing.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        public void paint(Graphics g) { //Error is this line
            g.drawRect(0, 72, 256, 72);
        }
    }
});
```

I just don't where else I can put a semi-colen. I am new to GUI programming, so I hope I did not make too bad of a mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You cannot nest two method in java:

```
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
            public void paint(Graphics g) { //Method inside a method is not allowed
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax problem.

```
JLabel lblAllOrNothing = new JLabel("All Or Nothing (4 BP)");
lblAllOrNothing.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // You can't define a method inside a method!!
    }
});
```

By the way to make custom painting in Swing you should override `paintComponent` instead of `paint`. Read more [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Answer (score 2):

- you can't to call paint() from AWT/Swing Listener
- this methods is automatically called by override this method for Container
- override paintComponent for JPanel instead of paint()

Comment: While your answer provides some useful clarity, it doesn't answer the question, which is asking why he's getting a syntax error

Comment: @StormeHawke your answer is wrong this isn't way how is painting in AWT/Swing done, follows Oracle tutorial linked in answer by nachokk, can be works by subclassing JLabel but this isn't implemented in your code posted here, btw subclassing is wrong idea for Swing

Comment: subclassing from concrete classes is almost a wrong idea for all OOP

Comment: I make no attempt to claim that my answer will actually do what he's wanting it to do.  I answered the question he asked, which was why he was getting a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a method inside of a method in Java.

Instead, do this

```
JLabel lblAllOrNothing = new JLabel("All Or Nothing (4 BP)");
    lblAllOrNothing.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
            //call the paint method here
        }

        //Move this method here
        public void paint(Graphics g) { //Error is this line
            g.drawRect(0, 72, 256, 72);
        }
    });
```

Note that this will not actually work functionally, but it illustrates why you're getting a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest a paint method in your mouseEntered method; perhaps you just want

```
JLabel lblAllOrNothing = new JLabel("All Or Nothing (4 BP)");
lblAllOrNothing.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
  @Override
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // public void paint(Graphics g) { 
    // g.drawRect(0, 72, 256, 72); }
    java.awt.Component c = e.getComponent();
    c.getGraphics().drawRect(0, 72, 256, 72);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant put a method into another one in java make the draw method out the listener
what you should do is just call the draw method in the listener method:

Answer (score 0):

this

```
new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // You can't define a method inside a method!!
    }
};
```

is an anonymous class.
now when you use it as an statement it will be used as };, and return an object, while when you use it as pass the object as a parameter the will use it as

```
fun(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // You can't define a method inside a method!!
    }
});
```